# How to post request for a particular field of array in mern stack

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern

The code does not add answer in answers array......pls explain how to write the correct way to implement it?
The 'id' is of the question, used for params.

Schema:

```
const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    qtitle:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    descofq:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    pic:{
        type:String,
        default:"no photo"
    },
    answers:[
        {
            answer:{
                type:String,
                required:false
            },
            picofa:{
                type:String,
                default:"no photo"
            },
            postedBy:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:"USER"
            }
        }
    ]
    }
})
```

POST request :

```
router.post('/answer/:id',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Question.findById(req.params.id).then(question=>{
        question.answers.answer = req.body.answer;
        question.save().then(result=>{
            res.json(result)
        }).catch(err=>{
            res.status(400).send(err);
        })
    }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(200).send(err);
    })
})
```

I also tried question.answers.answer.push(answer);
where the answer in brackets will be acquired from req.body, but this also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers field is an array you should specify which answer
inside answers array

```
router.post('/answer/:id',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Question.findById(req.params.id).then(question=>{
        question.answers.push(req.body.answers);
        question.save().then(result=>{
            res.json(result)
        }).catch(err=>{
            res.status(400).send(err);
        })
    }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(200).send(err);
    })
})
```

`Example:`
`req.body.answers = { answer: "bla bla..", picofa: "bla bla", postedBy: userId }`

**Another solution:**

```
router.post('/answer/:id',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Question.findById(req.params.id).then(question=>{
        question.answers[0].answer = req.body.answer;
        question.save().then(result=>{
            res.json(result)
        }).catch(err=>{
            res.status(400).send(err);
        })
    }).catch(err=>{
        res.status(200).send(err);
    })
})
```

Comment: can u explain the example part, like where I should write it, I applied it but its not working

Comment: example here is about request you should send from the client-side (like postman)

Answer (score 0):

Your answers is an array. You cannot set a value as an object.
If you want to add an object to array. Let use push function.

Ex:
question.answers.push({ answer: req.body.answer, postedBy: “userId” });
question.save()

Comment: used it but it's not working

Comment: You have to add an object. Because in schema you defined answer is nested field. You cannot push a string to it